# How do I kill Crystalisks?

Tags: borderlands-2

Crystalisks don't seem to have any elemental weaknesses and soak up a lot of bullets. Since they hit pretty hard to, I'm hoping for an easier way to hit them. Is there an easy way to kill them?

Comment: I believe they're totally immune to elemental damage too

Comment: @Rachel they're immune to elemental *effects* but they take normal damage from elemental guns

Comment: Thanks, I actually noticed that this weekend. I always thought they were totally immune but I either didn't see the damage, or was shooting them with a totally elemental gun.

Comment: @Rachel actually now that I've tried, they do appear immuned to Slag. Corrosion I know works though.

Answer (score 9):

**The Crystalisk** can be killed by sheer damage to anywhere on its body but, it takes the most damage when attacks are directed to the crystals on his legs. A melee attack can often break a crystal in a single hit, but sniper rifle and explosive weapons are quite good as well.

**Crystalisks weak spots:**

[image]

**Sources:** [Borderlands wikia](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Crystalisk),[Borderlands 2 wiki](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Crystalisk)

Comment: Zero can one hit knife crystals.

Comment: Explosive rifles shot at the ground between the crystalisk's feet can crit all the legs and some of the crystals on the body at once. This works pretty quickly if you don't want to get close enough for melee.

Answer (score 5):

**Crystalisks are weak to melee damage.** The crystals around their legs are their weak points (they only take damage here) and a single melee hit is often enough to destroy them. Even Crystalisk bosses have this extreme weakness. No matter your class or skills, melee is the best way to take care of these if at all possible.

Comment: Explosive damage shotguns or missile launchers can often take out a leg or more with one hit as well.

Comment: With guns it takes me ages to take one down - they soak up bullet damage and have a very damaging long range attack (one crystal bomb can wipe out your shields). With a bayonet gun and melee it takes 3 hits: one to each leg. As a siren it's even easier as you can hit all 3 with one phaselock.

Comment: I've found that using a melee attack on the legs works _really_ well indeed, letting you take out a crystalisk with three hits and no ammo. Failing that, if you're lucky enough to have an Infinity (that isn't vastly underleveled at that point) that's pretty effective too.

Answer (score 2):

Once you shatter all three of its crystal weak points, it dies.  Whether or not this is proportional to your crit damage regardless is unknown to me, but failing a powerful sniper rifle, I've found the best way to deal with them early on to be rockets and mirv grenades, but it gets a little expensive on the ammo front.  They are slow and actually rather docile, though, so if you don't HAVE to kill them to clear an area (like in the minecart quest) or as an objective, you can always just run away from them.

Answer (score 1):

Plain damage sniper rifles work wonders. Generally takes a couple shots per leg, if that.

Answer (score -1):

it works well with zeros action skill aswell

Comment: Could your write a short summary of what happens in the video, in case the video gets removed?